# Is there a mac and a linux version of GetLogicalDriveStrings() from win32api?

Tags: python, operating-system, pywin32, drive

The title basically explains the problem. I don't know a way to use `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` for os's besides windows, so it would be very helpful if someone could tell me what to use, and how. I need this so I can search all drives on a computer for a file, on the 3 main os's. There was a similar question to this one, but it had only one answer, which had a check mark, and it basically restated the problem. Plus, I couldn't comment cause I didn't have enough reputation since I mostly only read from stack exchange. Edit: I want my program to search the entire computer for a file, and run it, on the 3 main os's. That's all I want. I know windows has partitions that are treated as singular drives, and usb drives, so I want to find out how to search it all, and all of the partitions.

Comment: Proper operating systems have no need for constructs such as "logical drive strings".  A proper operating system can access multiple drives within a unified view of all file systems, starting from a single "root" directory, with no need for primitive constructs such as "logical drives".  

Comment: Conceptually, there's no such thing (a drive) on *Nix*. There are partitions (and mountpoints). You should edit the question, stating what exactly are you looking for (maybe a practical example).

Comment: Oh, yes. I haven't used linux in a while. I remember that now. What is the root path? Also, I believe mac is unix, does it work the same way? I never used mac in my life. Those comments are very helpful, thank you.